# I can copy a file, but my C# console app can't

Tags: c#, file-io

I've written a console app to help load code to servers, but I'm running into an issue running it. I'm getting a "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\...' is denied.

The app is comparing files, and those that are different it copies from a staging area to the server. It runs fine until I try to copy, then I get this error (e.g. I can read and compare the files, but not modify them). If I (manually) simply copy a file from one area to the other, no issues.

I was under the impression that a console app runs as the person who executes it.

The offending code is this:

```
File.Copy("correct staging path", "correct live path", true);
```

I was able to verify that the application is running as me using:

```
Environment.UserName (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name shows the same)
```

The destination path is a network share (e.g. \\servername\path)

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you have the Windows permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: The account your app is using to copy the files probably has different permissions than your actual account.

Comment: What is the statement to show (programatically) who a program is running as?

Comment: Have run into these errors so many times! windows permission strikes once again. You need to check at the folder level all the way down and see what access rights apply. Also what user STARTS the application? as the app will inherit those rights.

Comment: I am executing (starting) the application. In the same login session can verify that I could copy a file to the same directory.

Comment: you can use WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name to see who it is running as

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx you can also get the same exception if the file is read-only

Comment: @MatthewSanford That was it! Thanks. You should have made an answer.